# My Samsung Galaxy Note won't charge but will turn on for 1 second

Tags: charging, samsung-galaxy-note

I got my Samsung Galaxy Note about 5 months ago and three months into having it I dropped it and cracked the screen. The actual touch screen works it is just the glass that is broken. About a month or so after having dropped it I started using my mum's phone for a while, as the size was starting to be a problem and I was about to go to a festival. I have come to want to use my Note again and it hasn't let me charge it. Is this because of how long it has been since it was last charged or the strength of the charger that came with it? Or could be be something to do with the screen?

Comment: Have you left it charging for a long period of time, with it powered off, and still nothing?

Comment: The drop might have caused the charging component to malfunction, do you have a standalone charger that can charge the battery by itself?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can be because of so long time of charging. You must go for service center so that problem can be solved systematically.

Answer (score 0):

Remove back cover. Remove battery and refix it.

Refix Display ribbon cable.

Use another charging cable or possible start mobile with another battery. Clean battery three pin connector.

Connect Galaxy note to computer use USB cable. USB charge the mobile and if it is detected. Then mobile is fine.